# Fields are not initialized in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, gradle

The question applies only to the `name` and `lastName` fields;

There is a `User` class from which the `Customer` class is inherited. Accordingly, the fields of the parent class return `null`. The constructor of the `Customer` class has `super`.

USER:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    public User(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    User(String name, String lastName){ // Базовый конструктор для дочерних классов
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Поля
    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public String toString() { // Без этого метода вместо инициализированных строк выводятся символы.
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    // Методы
    public void changePassword(){// Сменить пароль

    }
}
```

CUSTOMER:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customer extends User {

    public Customer(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Customer(String name, String lastName){ // Пользовательский конструктор создается,
        super(name, lastName);                     // когда нам нужно создать новый экземпляр,
    }                                              // но у нас еще нет ID.


    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private double wallet;

//    private List<Order> orderList; 


    // Методы
    public void depositMoney(){// Внести деньги на счет

        }

    public void withdrawMoney(){// Вывести деньги со счета

        }

    public void makeOrder(){// Сделать заказ

        }
}
```

In this class, I pass the data to the constructor of the Customer class:

LoadDatabase:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(CustomerRepository repository) { // Добавляю данные для Customer
        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Customer("Artur", "Vartanyan")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Customer("Andrey", "Chekmaryov")));
        };
    }
```

[image]

[image]

P.S. The problem is not in LOMBOK, since the error does not disappear when the application starts without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `JPA`, the fields of the parent entity are not inherited by default: in the `Customer` table there will be no fields login, password, first name, last name. `JPA`, and explicitly specify `@MappedSuperclass` in the parent entity

Answer (score 0):

`repository.save` seems to be at fault here since although it is returning the right values nothing seems to be stored in the database, if you could post the implementation of how data is stored onto the database via the code, the next step would be figure what part of it is faulty when storing it in the database.